# Switching between dynamically added user controls showing old values

Tags: asp.net

Edit (more brief):

I have a control "configuration" with a tree view on the left and a list of panels on the right to which i add my controls. These elements are placed inside a table and surrounded by an ajax panel.

Let's say i have a tree node cars with two elements car1 and car2. When i click an item i save the ID and Type of the selected tree node inside hidden fields to be able to load the right user control on Page_Init

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var type = this.Request.Form["ctl00$MainContent$ctl00$typeId"];
        var id = this.Request.Form["ctl00$MainContent$ctl00$entityId"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(type) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {
            this.LoadUserControl(type, id);
        }
    }

 private void LoadUserControl(string type, string id)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(type) != 0)
        {
            switch (Convert.ToInt32(type))
            {
                case (int)SkTopics.Product:
                    this.AddUserControl("../Modules/Product.ascx", this.Product, type, id);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

private void AddUserControl(string controlName, Panel panel, string type, string id)
    {       
        // Init new user cotntrol
        control = (BaseControl)this.LoadControl(controlName);
        control.LoadEntityItem(Convert.ToInt32(id));

        // Setting the user control ID
        var replace = controlName.Replace("../Modules/", string.Empty);
        string userControlId = replace.Split('.')[0] + id;
        var targetControl = panel.FindControl(userControlId);

        if (object.Equals(targetControl, null))
        {
            control.ID = userControlId;
            control.DataBind();
            panel.Controls.Add(control);
        }
    }
```

On LoadEntityItem the data for this car are collected from the database and the values are set as Text of textboxes. When i now switch to the second car, the new values are displayed.

Problem: I change the values inside the textboxes and press the save button to call my save method of the user control. From now on, when i switch to the car 1 again, the values for car 2 are still displayed, although the data for car1 are filled. tO see the data for car1 i have to switch to a complete different type of control and then back to the car1.

Another problem is, that i have a binary image inside the user control which Data i fill on init. When i swith to the the next car, where there i no image configured, i set the image data to null, but the image from the previous car i show. Onyl if i set a different image data the new image is displayed.

There is something else i noticed:
Inside the user control i call a javascript funtion but this one is only called on clicking the the save button. It seems that there is a different between the switch of the tree node and the save button click ?

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "InitScrewPointsForDragging", "InitScrewPointsForDragging();", true);
```

I hope this was more brief than before.

Comment: can you explain your answer in more brief please

Comment: I updated my question, i hope it's more clear now. If not, just let me know and i will try again

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the reason for the issue is some improper viewstate handling and after I disable the view state it is working correctly at my side. Here is the code that I updated to have it work at my side:
this.control.EnableViewState = false;
this.control.ID = userControlId;